# Why does sizeof unnamed bitfield member structure print 1?

Tags: c, structure, sizeof, bit-fields

In the following program, declared unnamed bitfield member in structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct st{
    int : 1;
};

int main()
{
    struct st s;
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(s));  // print 1
}
```

Above program print the output 1.

Why does `sizeof(s)` print `1`?

Comment: what do you want it to print?

Comment: Because it's 1 byte large, I would guess ;)

Comment: I'm *amazed* it's 1. Must be UB. Just to check, what is sizeof(int) on your platform?

Comment: @Bathsheba Hey, look https://ideone.com/HcLohM

Comment: @usr This question about sizeof unnamed bit-field.

Comment: `sizeof` is relevant as a mean of revealing the UB.

Comment: @Bathsheba, `sizeof(int)` has absolutely nothing to do with it as far as the standard is concerned.  That the bitfield is declared with base type `int` places no requirement whatever on the size of the storage unit in which its value is stored.

Comment: @usr You are right. Yet there are few problems with the proposed duplicate. The question itself is not even suggesting there is any problem with the construct. And the the accepted answer is talking about UB just by the way, without concisely summarizing it in some clearly visible way, so you can easily miss it when reading "diagonally".

Comment: I am so glad that I got up today to complain about completely sane handling of UB of a worthless datatype...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof(s)` is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because there is no other named member in the structure.

**C11 6.7.2.1(P8) :**

> The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type,
>   within a translation unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for the
>   members of the structure or union. **If the struct-declaration-list contains no named
>   members, no anonymous structures, and no anonymous unions, the behavior is undefined.**
>   The type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list, and complete
>   thereafter.

If you write like this:

```
struct st{
        int : 1;
        int i : 5;
    };
```

So,`sizeof(s)` is ok because there is also named bit-field member in structure.

Comment: it is complete after} sizeof(st) would be UB in the struct declaration.

Comment: even if it is UB, it is a sane behavior that your compiler is imposing, compilers aren't required to do something bad because something isn't in the spec...

Comment: @GradyPlayer Would you define returning `1` as "bad" or "good"? It is indeed UB according to the standard.

Comment: @GradyPlayer, you seem to be misinterpreting the excerpt from the standard.  That the type is complete after the closing `}` has nothing to do with the fact that the program's and translator's behavior is undefined on account of the the structure having no named members, anonymous structure members, or anonymous union members.  Nor is the undefinedness limited to the result of the `sizeof` operator when applied to that type.

Comment: @rsp Even if you just add name to the first field the `sizeof` will be OK.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Re "*That the type is complete after the closing } has nothing to do with [...]*", Right, that part of the paragraph is irrelevant. The emphasised sentence, otoh, is relevant.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would define it as good if you can store the type in 1 byte...